# How to create a layout where a Button is at least as long as a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to achieve the following:

- I need to place a `Button` view somewhere in the layout
- There should be `TextView` right above this `Button` that is uses as label
- The size of the `Button` should depend on the size of the `TextView`. Since the app is localized the text width is not fixed but depends on the localized text that is uses as label.
- The `Button` should have a min. width of 150dp. If the width of the `TextView` is bigger than this, the `Button` should have the same width as the `TextView`.

This should look something like this:

```
Short Label
+-------------+
+-------------+

Very Long Label Text
+------------------+
+------------------+
```

I tried different solutions with LinearLayout or RelativeLayout as root layout but the problem is always the same: I was not able to fit the width of the `Button` to the width of the `TextView`. Giving the `Button` a minWidth of 150dp is no problem of course. But how to solve the second case with the long label?

```
<SomeRootLayout ...>
    <!-- also tried LinearLayout, but problem is the same... -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextAndLabelContainer"
        ...>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/labelTV" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</SomeRootLayout>
```

If the `Button` has a "match_parent" width the width is not aligned the the `TextView` but set to the complete screen width.

How can I solve this?

Comment: do it programatically..by getwidth() for textview...and if bigger then setwidth for button as same as textview....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextAndLabelContainer"
        ...>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/labelTV" //<== add this line
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/labelTV" //<== add this line
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/labelTV" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware that different alignments can be combined... This solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Ok..do something like:
layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/editTextAndLabelContainer"
    android:weightSum="2"
    ...>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelTV"
        android:layoutWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layoutWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/labelTV" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Or as suggest by Lena..

And in your Java code:
Add a `TextWatcher` in your textview `ontextchange` method..and in side after `textchange` method do something like:

```
int txtWidth = your_textViw.getWidth();
int btnWidth = your_button.getWidth();

if(txtWidth >= btnWidth)
  your_button.setWidth(txtWidth);
```